# What is a medical term for the belief that you're healthy when you're not?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, medical

What is a medical term, as in a mental or eating disorder, that means "a compulsion with being healthy, while actually being unhealthy," stemming primarily from a poor understanding of science, medicine, physiology, and the effects of exercise?

For example, a man who does hot yoga to "sweat out toxins" (MYTH!), but in reality, due to the effects of dehydration, his kidneys are retaining water and actually hanging onto any toxins that may be in his system.

Comment: http://180degreehealth.com/hyperchondriac/

Answer (score 1):

1. [Denial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial), denying certain conditions as a kind of possible "psychological self defense mechanism"
2. [Anosognosia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosognosia), Wikipedia defines this word as "deficit of self-awareness". Though it seems like this is actually related to injuries inside your brain and has nothing to do with just "psychological" reasons.

Both words seem to be kind of related. As Wikipedia describes it in the Article to Anosognosia *"Whilst this distinguishes the condition from denial, which is a psychological defense mechanism, attempts have been made at a unified explanation"*

I'm not quite sure if those words match your question, though. You're stating "*(...) stemming primarily from a poor understanding of science, medicine, physiology (...)*". I doubt that those words have anything to do with "poor understanding".

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[Word for the opposite of "hypochondriasis"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93344/word-for-the-opposite-of-hypochondria)

This post refers to "egodystonic" which is along the lines of believing what you want to believe, including the status of your health.