# Is there an antonym to 'hypochondria'/'hypochondriac'?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

[Hypochondria](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hypochondriac) is defined as

> an excessive preoccupation with and worry about one's health

Is there a word to describe the opposite reaction, as in a word to mean 'a nonchalant attitude towards one's health'? I thought about *hyperchondriac* but I don't think that word exists. Is there such a word in English?

Comment: Wow, looks like there's already a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93344/word-for-the-opposite-of-hypochondria) for this. When I was looking for duplicates, I searched for 'hypochondria antonym' and did not come across that. What's the best course of action now - delete, vote to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Anosognosia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosognosia):

> Anosognosia is viewed as a deficit of self-awareness, a condition in
>   which a person who suffers a certain disability seems unaware of the
>   existence of his or her disability.

Or [Anosodiaphoria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosodiaphoria):

> Anosodiaphoria is a condition in which a person who suffers disability
>   due to brain injury seems indifferent to the existence of their
>   handicap. Anosophoria is specifically used in association with
>   indifference to paralysis. ... Joseph Babinski first used the term
>   anosodiaphoria in 1914 to describe a disorder of the body schema in
>   which patients verbally acknowledge a clinical problem (such as
>   hemiparesis) but fail to be concerned about it. Anosodiaphoria follows
>   a stage of anosognosia, in which there may be verbal, explicit denial
>   of the illness, and after several days to weeks, develop the lack of
>   emotional response. Indifference is different from denial because it
>   implies a lack of caring on the part of the patient whom otherwise
>   acknowledges his or her deficit.

Also see [Word for the opposite of “hypochondria”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93344/word-for-the-opposite-of-hypochondria)