# Word to describe someone who allows himself to be ill?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I am looking for a word to describe a person who allows himself to become ill.

> Example: They can sense that depression is settling in again, they
>   know how to stave it off, yet they allow it to consume them and they
>   subsequently become suicidal or very ill.

I thought it may be self-indulgent, but have been told that's not correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Check here for a [similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226858/is-there-an-antonym-to-hypochondria-hypochondriac).

Comment: With regard to depression this is a difficult question.  Being depressed makes the individual have more difficulty making decisions, including the decision to not be depressed, even when he/she knows how.

Comment: It really is a difficult one! Im trying to explain to my therapist this emotion or action...as in i know how to stop myself falling into the 'trap' of a very deep depression, but i continue to just let myself fall...there must be a word or phrase?!

Answer (score 2):

How about ***neglectful***?

> negligent, neglectful, lax, slack, remiss mean culpably careless or indicative of such carelessness. negligent implies inattention to one's duty or business . neglectful adds a more disapproving implication of laziness **or deliberate inattention** . lax implies a blameworthy lack of strictness, severity, or precision . slack implies want of due or necessary diligence or care . remiss implies blameworthy carelessness shown in slackness, forgetfulness, or neglect . [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negligent)

Comment: Neglectful of one's own health seems to fit. :)

Answer (score -1):

A simple answer to that can be "Careless".

A careless person gets ill and does not care about his or her health.