# A word to describe a person who refuses to acknowledge illness in others

Tags: single-word-requests

Such as a parent refusing to believe a child is ill?
Hypochondriac is a person who constantly feels they themselves are ill. I am looking for a word to describe a person who refuses to acknowledge another person is ill.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons people might do this, so a lot of words. This sounds a *bit* like ["Word for the opposite of 'hypochondriasis'"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/93344/58761). If you're just looking for another word such as "in denial"/"unrealistic"/"opimistic"/etc., perhaps you can explain by giving some context and using it in a sentence leaving a blank for the word.

Comment: A wife with a high fever tells her husband she can't go to work due to her illness. The husband responds,"Sure you can, you are fine". To which the wife says, "I am sick don't be such a_______".

Comment: Would mean an example like "Though it was plainly obvious her new child had webbed toes, the new mother was a __________, so refused to believe it"

Comment: Since "in others" is a part of the request I am doubtful this is a duplicate. Hypochondriasis is a disorder of self-diagnosis, not other-diagnosis, no?

Answer (score 0):

Although its literal meaning is not right, the Urban Dictionary recognizes **'hyperchondriac'** as someone who denies illness.

Answer (score -1):

To fill in the blank in your example sentence in the comments, this first came to mind:

> [***hard-ass***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hard-ass) - (US, slang) someone who is tough and uncompromising

And that definition suggests the non-slang:

> [***uncompromising***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncompromising) -  not willing to change a decision, opinion, method, etc

I'd still personally call the person a *hardass.*  It is close to *stickler* in meaning.

Comment: See, some hardass voted this down.