# Antonym for Hypochondriac or another word completely?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Sample sentence:

> Some people think that Veronica is a workaholic but what they don't know about her is that **she actually suffers from a very debilitating and un-diagnosed chronic illness** – she's really the opposite of a hypochondriac.

I am not satisfied with previous answers to this question.

**Q:** What do you call people who are misdiagnosed or judged by their doctors (especially in the US) as "hypochondriacs" when in fact they are suffering from real illnesses?

They are neither overly anxious or nonchalant about their actual condition.  After years of being mis-treated, un-treated, mis-diagnosed, or un-diagnosed these sufferers go back into the workplace and stop talking to anyone about their condition because it is the most practical thing to do. They pretend they are perfectly healthy and silently suffer through their pains/symptoms.  I don't know any hypochondriacs but I know dozens of these types of people.

Maybe the word I am looking for is the inability of doctors and society in general to cope with the actual sea of suffering/illness that there is in our society.

Comment: This is a very vague question as posed - do you mean " undiagnosed sufferers from an illness" or "sufferers from an as yet unrecognized illness"? Either way, there would seem to be no external, objective way of differentiating them from hypochondriacs.

Comment: This is an important question, and it has me thinking. I haven't got any answers yet, but I will say this: one of the most important purposes of language is for solving social problems at all levels. Problems without adequate words to express them coherently and persuasively are problems which haven't been and cannot be skillfully addressed as of yet. Poor communication is in itself a social issue, depending on the severity of the problem. And problems involving life and health or well-being, whether those of one or a sea of individuals, should rate near the top of the societal priority list.

Comment: If this is a genuine disease then the medical profession will apply a suitable term to it. Until they do so, there will be just vague, unauthorised descriptions which cannot be accepted as valid.

Comment: Hyperchondriac, perhaps? ;-)  It is not etymologically sound, the word *hypochondria* being derived from a term meaning 'lateral regions of the upper abdomen' - but works as a frivolous coining.

Comment: (1) @TimLymington: I believe that this is basically a good question, and that you’re measuring it by an irrelevant yardstick. Just because there’s “no external, objective way of differentiating” people who are ____ from people who aren’t _____ ***at the time*** doesn’t mean that there shouldn’t be a word for _____. Go into a store and look at a few identical containers (e.g., jugs of milk or bottles of pills). Which one is *tainted* or *contaminated* ? You can’t tell without opening them. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Or consider Schroedinger’s Cat.  You can’t tell whether it’s alive or dead until you open the box (and, come on now; we all know that the cat is alive ***or*** dead, and not both).  People who are _____ can be differentiated from hypochondriacs years later, when they are finally diagnosed.  [Mari-Lou A seems to understand it.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/432348/26083#432524)  (2) Regretfully, I am voting to close this as unclear because I don’t understand what being a “workaholic” has to do with the question.

Comment: Why wouldn't "mis–" or "dysdiagnosed" fit your bill, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/93344/73094

Comment: @Scott The bit about Veronica being a workaholic is distracting and doesn’t seem to make an awful lot of sense, but I don’t think it makes the question as a whole unclear.

Answer (score 1):

For the sufferers who are afflicted with chronic pain or hidden illnesses which may or may not be diagnosed by the medical profession, there is a term for this condition:

> **Invisible disability**
>
> Invisible disabilities are chronic illnesses and conditions that significantly impair normal activities of daily living. **In the United States, 96% of people with chronic medical conditions show no outward signs of their illness,** and 10% experience symptoms that are considered disabling.

And there's an interesting article online called *[Chronic pain: The “invisible” disability](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/chronic-pain-the-invisible-disability-2017042811360)*. The author describes the frustration of managing their chronic pain, long after the illness has been diagnosed and treated

> …a study by the Institute of Medicine discovered that pain can endure long after the illness or injury that caused its initial onset has been treated or healed, until it eventually evolves, or devolves, into its own disease. That is, pain is no longer indicative of another prognosis — it *is* the prognosis, and a disabling one at that.

However, there doesn't appear to be a single word that describes the category of **silent** or **invisible sufferers**. The only single word that comes close is ***[stoic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stoic)***, which Oxford Dictionaries define as

> *A person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining*.

If the OP described this group as the **antithesis of hypochondriacs** the meaning would be understood.  Finally, the most common phrase appears to be **[living with chronic pain](https://www.google.it/search?biw=1313&bih=660&ei=rwiQWtu2DcnWwALzkpbICQ&q=living%20%22with%20chronic%20pain%22&oq=living%20%22with%20chronic%20pain%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.13271.15478.0.15839.2.2.0.0.0.0.135.264.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.264...0i7i30k1.0.Vxu_TXGI43c)**, which is universally understood and requires no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Anosognosia. Anosognosia, also called "lack of insight," is a symptom of severe mental illness experienced by some that impairs a person's ability to understand and perceive his or her illness. It is the single largest reason why people with schizophrenia or bipolar disorder refuse medications or do not seek treatment.